# What are the best practices for abstracting common workflow processing in Python Pandas data science applications?

Tags: python, pandas

We have a number of Python-Pandas data science applications at work that follow a very stereotyped workflow:

1. Retrieve some data
2. Perform some common processing
3. Perform some specialized processing
4. Retrieve some more data based on previous processing
5. [More of the above...]

All of the above steps are performing some creation, manipulation, etc. of Pandas data frames. The specialized processing steps are frequently different, but the bulk of the workflow is the same from application to application.

I would like to factor out the common parts of these workflows with the result being one application that can support configurable workflow steps.

Normally, I would handle this using standard object-oriented programming techniques and software patterns. For example, I might represent the various workflow steps as objects and thread the Pandas data frame state through a list of these objects (similar to chain-of-responsibility or an inverted visitor pattern).

**But**, these applications are developed and utilized by data scientists, not software engineers. They need to be able to examine data at each stage in the workflow, and iPython is all they can handle. Unfortunately, using iPython to "debug" even trivially simple object-oriented programs in iPython has proven to be too cumbersome.

I've scoured the internet, but haven't been able to find any reasonable solutions to this or similar problems. What are the best practices for dealing with this type of situation?

Comment: What do you mean by ipython? Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: I do not see any intrinsic incompatibility between *be able to examine data at each stage in the workflow* and OO refactoring.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: IPython = Interactive Python, not Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @ChristopherLewis right, but those terms are sometimes used synonymously, which is why I asked for clarification. So is the issue that the data scientists are only comfortable with REPLs of some sort? IOW: what is the alternative, an IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: @Tnerual: There's no intrinsic incompatibility. The impedance mismatch appears to be between the desire to have an environment that works like R (Pandas makes this somewhat doable given how easily data frames can be examined and modified) and robust, maintainable, etc. software (I'm not sure how this is accomplished in the R world).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: "So is the issue that the data scientists are only comfortable with REPLs of some sort?" Pretty much, once you tell them that they have to navigate through some object layers and everything can't be in global scope the user support burden becomes too high.

Comment: @ChristopherLewis I deleted my last comment, but actually I stand by it. I don't think it's acceptable for a "data scientist" (which is my title, but I'm pigeonholed into one set of problems, and it's variable as a title) to only be able to operate within such a small subset of software design. I can cobble together a full-stack solution in a REPL that's integrated with our systems, then pass to software engineers for production. I think in-house training from software engineers would be useful. If anything it makes them more employable, so they shouldn't object.